# "Command not found" in ifconfig | grep IF statement

Tags: grep, ifconfig

I'm trying to check if my ethernet adapter is hardwired. For that I have the following secton in my code:

```
if 'ifconfig | grep "status: active" | head -2 | tail -1 | awk {'print$2'} | cut -f1 -d:'; then
  wired_status=True
  echo $wired_status
```

For this section of code it gives the following error:

./tst_wired.sh: line 27: ifconfig | grep "status: active" | head -2 | tail -1 | awk {print} | cut -f1 -d:: command not found

Typing "ifconfig" in my terminal is recognized and works.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that as well thinking that was the issue. However, changing it to backticks yields the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've used apostrophe instead of backtick characters:

```
` and ' are different
```

Comment: I found the issue. The IF statement was generating output and the OS interpreted is as a command. Using if [[ `ifconfig | grep "status: active" | head -2 | tail -1 | awk {'print$2'} | cut -f1 -d:` -eq "active" ]].  solved the issue.

Comment: This is still horribly verbose. The twisty maze of [useless `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) etc can be refactored to `ifconfig | awk '/status: active/ { split(/:/, n, $2) } END { print n[1] }'` and if you only care if it's "active" or not, you can further simplify to `ifconfig | awk ¨/status: active/ && $2 ~ /^active:/ { rc=1 } END { if(rc) print "True" }'` and get rid of the shell `if` statement entirely.